# UserScript to modify Google Search to auto-enable Tools button and still see the results count

Tags: javascript, userscripts

**Post updated with working code below...**

The unmodified default [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=userscript) home page [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKynu.jpg) with the handy results count. If the Tools button is pressed, the Tools Bar saying "Any Time" appears [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXvgz.jpg) - but it also removes the results count even though there's room for both. My goal is to have the Tools button automatically pressed on loading the page (showing the "Any Time" drop down) AND still showing the "results count" all at once [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CvMP.png).

I think it should be possible because when the Tools button is pressed, I can force the page to temporarily display both the Results Count and Tools bar with the Firefox Inspector by editing

```
class="appbar hdtb-ab-o"
```

[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeXD4.jpg), to

```
class="appbar"
```

[Shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNtb3.jpg).

Searching for UserScript examples relevant to modifying a Class element, I found [things like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884983/change-class-value-using-greasemonkey) but when I modified the example to target this class, the add/remove calls didn't seem to do anything. Another hour of reading docs has me suspecting maybe the issue is due to the Google Search page being dynamic. Trying to adapt examples I found related to MutationObservers just yields syntax errors, probably because I'm still too inexperienced.

I'm a complete newbie regarding Javascript/CSS syntax and formatting although I have a fair bit of experience in old-school assembly language development. I'm learning this web stuff and having fun with UserScript but so far am only able to cut, paste, merge and modify other people's working scripts. At this point, with nothing I'm trying even appearing to change anything, I feel like I'm just fumbling in the dark and unlikely to kludge or stumble my way forward by poking around. It all seemed pretty straightforward when I started. Just change that one line of code from *class="appbar hdtb-ab-o"* to *class="appbar"* and it's done! I now realize how naive I was... :-)

**Edit to Add:** Here's my working solution. It turns out I was indeed barking up the wrong tree and overthinking the problem.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        New script google.com
// @namespace   https://greasyfork.org/pt-BR/users/821661
// @match       https://www.google.com/search*
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
    'use strict';
    GM_addStyle(`
        .LHJvCe {
            opacity: unset !important;
            top: 0px !important;
        }
    `);
})();
```

Comment: seems what you want to do is `document.getElementById("hdtbMenus").style.cssText = "text-align:right;display:block;padding-top:3px;padding-bottom:7px;top:57px";`

Comment: That (sorta) worked! Well, it was close enough to get me in the ballpark. After playing around with it I realized toggling the date dropdown was kind of backward because it was forced visible regardless of (and out of sync with) Tools button state.

It's better to force the Result Count to be visible instead. So, another half-hour of fumbling around trying different IDs and I found it. I'll update my post now with the final code.